# Linq requests in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, request

This is my XML file:

```
<lines>
<line>
    <cell width="96" align="left" styleclass="5">Madame</cell>
    <cell width="129" align="left" styleclass="5">NATHALIE</cell>
    <cell width="187" align="left" styleclass="5">REGINENSI</cell>
    <cell width="296" align="left" styleclass="5">production@holyfruits.com</cell>
    <cell width="79" align="left" styleclass="5">CL00295</cell>
</line>
<line>
    <cell width="96" align="left" styleclass="5">Madame</cell>
    <cell width="129" align="left" styleclass="5">NICOLE</cell>
    <cell width="187" align="left" styleclass="5">BAROIN</cell>
    <cell width="296" align="left" styleclass="5">nbaroin@skendy-paris.com</cell>
    <cell width="79" align="left" styleclass="5">CL00022</cell>
</line>
</lines>
```

I'm trying to get all cell values of a line, where the line of `width="79" == CL00295` but I'm strugling to find the correct syntax for the linq request. Here what I did, which doesn't works:

```
var results = from sheet in doc.Descendants("line")
                          where sheet.Descendants("cell").ToString().ToLower() == listeClients[comboBoxClients.SelectedIndex].Id.ToLower()
                          select new
                          {
                              Value = sheet.Descendants("cell")
                                    .Where(t => t.Attribute("width")
                                    .Value == "96") // Civ
                                    .First().Value,
                              Value2 = sheet.Descendants("cell")
                                    .Where(t => t.Attribute("width")
                                    .Value == "129") // Prenom
                                    .First().Value,
                              Value3 = sheet.Descendants("cell")
                                    .Where(t => t.Attribute("width")
                                    .Value == "187") // Nom
                                    .First().Value,
                              Value4 = sheet.Descendants("cell")
                                    .Where(t => t.Attribute("width")
                                    .Value == "296") // Email
                                    .First().Value,
                              Value5 = sheet.Descendants("cell")
                                    .Where(t => t.Attribute("width")
                                    .Value == "79") // Code
                                    .First().Value
                          }.ToString();
```

I guess the wrong part of my code is

```
where sheet.Descendants("cell").ToString().ToLower() == listeClients[comboBoxClients.SelectedIndex].Id.ToLower()
```

But couldn't figure how to make it work...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: your xml has not a single root?

Comment: I edited with the root <lines>

Comment: Try following :             var results = doc.Descendants("line").Where(x => x.Elements("cell").Any(y => (string)y.Attribute("width") == "79" && (string)y == "CL00295")).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file named "xml.xml":

```
<lines>
    <line>
        <cell width="96" align="left" styleclass="5">Madame</cell>
        <cell width="129" align="left" styleclass="5">NATHALIE</cell>
        <cell width="187" align="left" styleclass="5">REGINENSI</cell>
        <cell width="296" align="left" styleclass="5">production@holyfruits.com</cell>
        <cell width="79" align="left" styleclass="5">CL00295</cell>
    </line>
    <line>
        <cell width="96" align="left" styleclass="5">Madame</cell>
        <cell width="129" align="left" styleclass="5">NICOLE</cell>
        <cell width="187" align="left" styleclass="5">BAROIN</cell>
        <cell width="296" align="left" styleclass="5">nbaroin@skendy-paris.com</cell>
        <cell width="79" align="left" styleclass="5">CL00022</cell>
    </line>
</lines>
```

Then I extracted lines with an attribute named width with a value of `79`, with xelement's value of `CL00295`, after that i extract the cells of the corrisponding lines.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml.xml");
List<XElement> cells = doc.Descendants("line").Where(z => z.Descendants("cell").Any(x => x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Name == "width")?.Value == "79" && x.Value == "CL00295"))?.Elements("cell").ToList();
```

This answer contains all the nullchecks!